# Is there any GUI tool for Upstart

Tags: configuration, gui, services, upstart

Is there currently any GUI based application to show currently running services, with buttons to start and stop services?

It doesn't necessarily need to be able to set boot up behaviour.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, `jobs-admin` is the new GUI which uses `jobservice` to configure Upstart scripts.  It's in Maverick's repos, but there's a PPA available at https://launchpad.net/~jpeddicord/+archive/jobtools for Lucid.

Comment: `jobs-admin` looks interesting, I'll have to keep an eye on it.

Comment: I just tried this tool, version 0.8.0.  It is similar to BUM with fewer features, and even when I run it as su it is not able to edit my init levels because of what seems to be a bug?

Comment: I installed mysql and it doesn't show in the jobs-admin. Not sure why.

Comment: Here's the jobs-admin bug in question, FYI: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jobs-admin/+bug/947674

Comment: I only see four services by default, then if I choose "Show protected jobs" from the Jobs menu I get lots more. However they are greyed out and I can't do anything to them. I'm running `jobs-admin` as root. I also don't see the service I wanted to disable: `lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

I believe Boot-Up Manager is what you're looking for (package name is `bum`).

[image: bum]

Comment: Are you sure that works with Upstart scripts, not just init scripts?  The package description doesn't say it works with Upstart...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with upstart, though aren't most services still `init` scripts?

Comment: This doesn't work with upstart the way you would think.

Comment: upstart is quickly overtaking sysinit, because you can write an upstart equiv that is less than a half of screenful (80x25 screen) what may have been 4 pages or more before! Personally, ALL my new scripts are upstart. even with skeleton, its still a pain in the butt to manage sysvinit scripts and they are lacking in job-specific confirmity and that leads to security issues, etc, etc..