# How do I start a service after the network is up?

Tags: startup, services

In my case, squid is started before DHCP has written a new `/etc/resolv.conf` which results in odd errors (timeouts, 504 Gateway) when I try to load a page in the web browser.

As I see it, the correct solution would be to start squid only after dhcpd/NetworkManager/whoever (?) has finished configuring the network.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?. Or more concrete, are you using SysV or upstart?.

Comment: I'm on 11.10 and upstart.

Comment: Check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs or http://askubuntu.com/questions/3341/is-there-any-gui-tool-for-upstart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should modify the squid.conf file in /etc/init so that it only starts when network is up:

```
start on (started networking)
```

You can find much more info [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on), and looking at the files in your /etc/init/ dir.

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs) should also help. If you prefer to configure it with a GUI, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3341/is-there-any-gui-tool-for-upstart).

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples from the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

[To start a job when eth0 is available](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#to-start-a-job-when-eth0-is-available)

```
start on net-device-up IFACE=eth0
```

[To start once a non-loopback device has come up](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#normal-start):

```
start on net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

Note: `net-device-up` is not a regular job, it's an ["Ubuntu well-known event"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific).